# LibGdx Box2d Platformer Jump implementation

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I am using Box2D in LibGdx to create a platformer game.I have an algorithm which converts tiles to fixtures.And i am using Contact Listener to determine if the player is in the air or not, but the problem is, because i am using fixtures that are next to each other,

```
(P)-->
```

|tile| |tile| |tile|

contact listener calls contact end after calling contact begin when i pass the adjacent tile and sets MOB_AIR value to true resulting i can't jump even though i'm on the ground.

Other parts of the code (mob and box2d world) works fine, because i can jump when i'm newly landed or in-between the tiles.

If you experienced the same issue before, is there a good way to implement this jumping?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQPd3.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h33xb.png

sorry for my bad English, any helps will be appreciated.

PS: Also problem is not about due box2d polygon-polygon collison glitches, i use chainshape for player and polygons for tiles.
`

```
        public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
            Fixture x1 = contact.getFixtureA();
            Fixture x2 = contact.getFixtureB();

            if(x1.getUserData()!=null && x2.getUserData()!=null){
                if(x1.getUserData().equals("sensor") && x2.getUserData().equals("x")){
                    mob.setState(Mob.ON_AIR, false);
                }

                else if(x2.getUserData().equals("sensor") && x1.getUserData().equals("x")){
                    mob.setState(Mob.ON_AIR, false);
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void endContact(Contact contact) {
            Fixture x1 = contact.getFixtureA();
            Fixture x2 = contact.getFixtureB();

            if(x1.getUserData()!=null && x2.getUserData()!=null){
                if(x1.getUserData().equals("sensor") && x2.getUserData().equals("x")){

                    mob.setState(Mob.ON_AIR, true);

                }
                else if(x2.getUserData().equals("sensor") && x1.getUserData().equals("x")){

                    mob.setState(Mob.ON_AIR, true);
                }
            }
        }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of simply setting the state when you get a begin/end contact, try incrementing and decrementing a counter to keep track of how many things the sensor is touching.